# Web.Config SQL Connection

Tags: sql-server, web-config

My Web.Debug.Config code:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NextLevel"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-RTOUFCH\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=NextLevel;Integrated Security=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

My CSharp code:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NextLevel"].ConnectionString;
```

I keep getting a null reference error.

When I attempt to iterate through the connection strings, it finds one named "LocalSQLServer" which is not even in my web.Debug.config file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the `connectionStrings` section look like from `web.config`.  And, are you sure you are running the Debug configuration?

Comment: Are you compiling and running in Debug mode or Release mode? Do you have multiple connectionStrings sections in the .config file(s)? There should only be one in each file and it should have the XPath of /configuration/connectionStrings.

Comment: I would also suggest you to publish web.config, web.debug.config, and web.release.config. If you have those files.

Answer (score 0):

[That last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73325114/web-config-sql-connection/73346315#comment129500512_73325114) by [ThomasArdal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758765/thomasardal):

> I would also suggest you to publish web.config, web.debug.config, and web.release.config. If you have those files.

allowed me to figure out my problem.

I was updating `web.debug.config` when I should have been updating `web.config`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="NextLevel"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NextLevel;Integrated Security=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Check with this instead!